# C# Conditionally assign variable value type

Tags: c#, interface

I need to know if there's a better way to write this code. In `SomeMethod()` below, I wish to return `IMyInterface` type, but the object that is returned could be created as `Class1` or `Class2`, based on a condition. `Class2` has an additional property that only makes sense if the condition is false.

```
public interface IMyInterface
{
    int Prop1 { get; set; }

    string Prop2{ get; set; }
}

public class Class1: IMyInterface
{
    public int Prop1 { get; set; }

    public string Prop2{ get; set; }
}

public class Class2: IMyInterface
{
    public int Prop1 { get; set; }

    public string Prop2{ get; set; }

    public string AdditionalProp{ get; set; }
}

public class SomeClass
{ 
  public IMyInterface SomeMethod(bool cond)
  {
      IMyInterface foo;
      if (cond)
      {
         foo = new Class1();
      }
      else    
      {
         foo = new Class2();
      }
       foo.Prop1 = 1;
       foo.Prop1 = "1";

       if (!cond)
       {
           foo.AdditionalProp = "2";
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a standard software design methodology known as the *factory pattern*.

Comment: This question is not even a half hour old and an answer has already been accepted so maybe it's a moot point to ask, but are you asking if `SomeMethod()` could be better written, or if the whole thing could be better structured for users of `Class1`/`Class2`?

Comment: I wasn't aware of the factory pattern, and when I came up with the above code it looked a little odd to me (setting instance values to different classes based on a condition). So wanted to make sure that the style is ok to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like [factory pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern#C#). The only difference between your code and the code in the linked example is that in your case the parameter of factory's get method would be bool, not type. Here's how it would look:

```
public interface IMyInterface
{
    int Prop1 { get; set; }

    string Prop2{ get; set; }
}

public class Class1: IMyInterface
{
    public int Prop1 { get; set; }

    public string Prop2{ get; set; }
}

public class Class2: IMyInterface
{
    public int Prop1 { get; set; }

    public string Prop2{ get; set; }

    public string AdditionalProp{ get; set; }
}

/// <summary>
/// Implementation of Factory - Used to create objects
/// </summary>
public class Factory
{
    public IMyInterface GetClass(bool condition)
    {
        if (condition)
        {
            return new Class1();
        }
        else
        {
            return new Class2();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Aside from changing the method name and not initializing the returned instance, I'm not seeing how this is different from what's in the question.  Is your contention that because it follows a known pattern the code in the question is good (by the original text of the question)?  If so, it's really your Wikipedia link that's doing all the work in this answer.

Comment: I also don't see an elegant way of setting the property values once an `IMyInterface` instance is returned. You'd have to cast it back to `Class2` to do that. But the OP accepted this as the answer, although I'd be interested in why he did that. The question might not have provided us with all the details and so this answer might address something we did not see.

Comment: @BACON my intention was to point the OP to the factory pattern so that he can make his research, but I agree it doesn't answer whether it's good or bad.

Comment: @Thomas I skipped setting the properties before returning as it's a trivial task for the OP to complete.

Comment: The reason I accepted this is because the answer pointed me to the factory pattern which I wasn't aware of, and the link gave me good amount of information.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your requirement correctly, following approach solves your problem.

You can intialize the objects inline:

```
public IMyInterface SomeMethod(bool cond)
{

    IMyInterface foo;
    if (cond)
    {
        foo = new Class1();
    }
    else
    {
        foo = new Class2() { AdditionalProp = "2" };
    }

    foo.Prop1 = 1;
    foo.Prop2 = "1";

    return foo;
}
```

Comment: My interface has many properties (not shown in my example above), hence I didn't want to duplicate the assignment of the properties. I only assign the common properties once (avoid duplicate assignment code), and only assign the additional property if the condition is true.

Comment: @Crust3, that would have been an important piece of information.

Comment: @Crust3 I have edited the answer for common assignment. Basically you can intialize objects with properties which are not common and common properties can assigned separately.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an elegant solution:

```cs
public IMyInterface SomeMethod(bool cond)
{
    return cond
        ? (IMyInterface) new Class1 { Prop1 = 1, Prop2 = "1" }
        : new Class2 { Prop1 = 1, Prop2 = "1", AdditionalProp = "2" };
}
```

Comment: Note that one of those will need a cast to `IMyInterface`, otherwise the conditional ?: expression has no type.